# Websphere 9 maven remote deployment

Tags: maven, jenkins, deployment, websphere

My springboot application builds into a WAR file (using Jenkins). I want to automate the remote deployment to Websphere 9.

I have read around and it seems there is no maven plugin for deployment to websphere 9 but ant support is pretty good. So, I'm using maven ant plugin to help running those ant tasks. I started with attempt to list the applications installed, just to see if it works. However I'm running into an exception related to localization:

> [ERROR] C:\DEV\ant-was-deploy.xml:81:
> java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name
> com.ibm.ws.profile.resourcebundle.WSProfileResourceBundle, locale
> en_US

My ant-was-deploy.xml is referenced from pom.xml:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <id>id123</id>
                <phase>clean</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <locales>es</locales>
                    <target>
                        <ant antfile="${basedir}/ant-was-deploy.xml">
                            <target name="listApps"/>
                        </ant>
                    </target>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

ant-was-deploy.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="websphere" default="listApps" basedir="." >
    <target name="listApps" >
        <taskdef name="wsListApps" classname="com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.ListApplications" classpath="${wasHome.dir}/plugins/com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar" />
        <wsListApps
            profileName="AppServ01"
            wasHome="C:\\opt\\IBM\\WebSphere\\AppServer"
        />
    </target>
</project>
```

I think the error comes from com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar. Inside it has WSProfileResourceBundle.class and WSProfileResourceBundle_en.class but not WSProfileResourceBundle_en_US.class (name is just an assumption - I have copied the bundle with this name inside the jar but it didn't work).

I also tried to set the locale for the entire plugin but it seems that localization for this plugin is not implemented properly (no impact in my case - I set the locale to 'es' but still got the error for en_US).

I also tried to pass system parameters to maven command: *mvn clean -Duser.language=fr -Duser.country=FR*
It didn't work either.

So, my question is if there is a way to change the locale before the ant script? If I can set it to 'en' probably it will find the right resource bundle.

I'm fairly new to Websphere, if there is another solution to automate the remote deployment to websphere 9 I would be happy to hear it. I would rather not use scripts on target server or Jenkins plugin but if there is no other way ...

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. In my case, i was using an AppServer name (AppSrv1 instead of AppSrv01) that did not exist anymore, in my maven settings.xml.
The right server name solved the issue.